# How do I take the average of every 1500th row in R, 12 times?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a set of EMG data. There are 9 columns, each representing a muscle. In each column, there are 18,000 rows. The EMG data is measured at 1000Hz. Each column contains 12 individual events, each 1.5 seconds long. I want to create an event (1.5 seconds or 1500 frames long), that is an average of the 12 individual events. I have a way to do it in excel, using the formula `=AVERAGE(A2,A1502,A3002,A4502,A6002,A7502,A9002,A10502,A12002,A13502,A15002,A16502)`
and repeating that for the entire column. However, I want to do it in R as that will be more efficient once I loop through multiple files.

I tried a few iterations along the lines of

`````
obs_len <- 1500
avg_col <- apply(data, 2, function(x) {
  sapply(1:obs_len, function(i) {
    mean(x[(i-1)*n_obs + 1:i*n_obs])
  })
})````
as suggested by ChatGPT, but nothing worked. Some returned partial data that looked wrong along with NA values. Any suggestions are appreciated.
`````

Comment: To clarify, I presume in excel this formula would only be copied down from row 2:1501?

Comment: @JonSpring yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(obs_id = (row_number()-1) %% 1500)) %>%
  summarize(across(1:9, mean))
```

This would make a column called `obs_id` that measures where in the 1500-observation cycle we are, from 0 to 1499 (and then repeating another eleven times). We group by that number, so the 1st row and the 1501st and 3001st etc. are in group 0, and then we take the mean across columns 1 to 9. This should output a data frame that is 9 columns by 1500 rows.